# Conditional counter-probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Given we have two classes, $C_1$ and $C_2$, and a binomial Random Variable which can take on the values $1$ or $0$.

Given that $P(X = 1 | C = 1) = p$, since there are only two outcomes for X , $P(X=0 | C = 1) = (1-p)$.

Can we however conclude something about $P(X=1 | C=0)$?

Comment: I think you can not conclude

Comment: You can not conclude. Try with $P(X=1 \text{ and } C=1) = p/2$ and $P(X=0 \text{ and } C=1) = (1-p)/2$.